# Android TextView setText() vs append() and Editable.Factory

Tags: android, textview

To create a new `Editable` from a TextView, you need an `Editable.Factory`:

```
private final Editable.Factory editableFactory = new Editable.Factory() {
    @Override
    public Editable newEditable(CharSequence source) {
        Log.d("TAG", "newEditable() is called");
    }
};

myTextView.setEditableFactory(editableFactory);
```

I noticed that `newEditable()` is only called if `append()` is called but not when `setText()` is called, some thing like this:

```
myTextView.setText("some text");    // does not work
myTextView.append("some text");     // works
```

Any Idea why this behavior? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the append method in TextView.java at line 5731:

> Convenience method to append the specified text to the TextView's
> display buffer, upgrading it to {@link
> android.widget.TextView.BufferType#EDITABLE} if it was not already
> editable.

`append(CharSequence text)` will call `append(text, 0, text.length())` which contains the following:

```
if (!(mText instanceof Editable)) {
    setText(mText, BufferType.EDITABLE);
}
```

`setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type)` calls `setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type, boolean notifyBefore, int oldlen)`.
This method contains some if statements that will change the functionality depending on the type.
Line 6156:

```
if (type == BufferType.EDITABLE || getKeyListener() != null || needEditableForNotification) {
    createEditorIfNeeded();
    mEditor.forgetUndoRedo();
    Editable t = mEditableFactory.newEditable(text);
    text = t;
    setFilters(t, mFilters);
    InputMethodManager imm = getInputMethodManager();
    if (imm != null) imm.restartInput(this);
```

Therefore you should be able to use `public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type)` too if you wanted.